# How to parse the Multiple OBR Segment in HL7 using HAPI

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

The following text is the hl7 message , i could able to parse many segments except NTE segment .'m using HAPI to parse the hl7 messages.'m newvbie to HL7 so please can any one suggest relevant classes in [HAPI](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/devbyexample.html) how to parse NTE segments ? it would be better if explanation is  with few examples,

```
MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3629|P|2.2
PID|2|2161348462|20809880170|1614614|20809880170^TESTPAT||19760924|M|||^^^^
00000-0000|||||||86427531^^^03|SSN# HERE
ORC|NW|8642753100012^LIS|20809880170^LCS||||||19980727000000|||HAVILAND
OBR|1|8642753100012^LIS|20809880170^LCS|008342^UPPER RESPIRATORY
CULTURE^L|||19980727175800||||||SS#634748641 CH14885 SRC:THROA
SRC:PENI|19980727000000||||||20809880170||19980730041800||BN|F
OBX|1|ST|008342^UPPER RESPIRATORY CULTURE^L||FINALREPORT|||||N|F||| 19980729160500|BN
ORC|NW|8642753100012^LIS|20809880170^LCS||||||19980727000000|||HAVILAND
OBR|2|8642753100012^LIS|20809880170^LCS|997602^.^L|||19980727175800||||G|||
19980727000000||||||20809880170||19980730041800|||F|997602|||008342
OBX|2|CE|997231^RESULT 1^L||M415|||||N|F|||19980729160500|BN
NTE|1|L|MORAXELLA (BRANHAMELLA) CATARRHALIS
NTE|2|L| HEAVY GROWTH
NTE|3|L| BETA LACTAMASE POSITIVE
OBX|3|CE|997232^RESULT 2^L||MR105|||||N|F|||19980729160500|BN
NTE|1|L|ROUTINE RESPIRATORY FLORA
```

**EDITED**

Here I am supposed to parse multiple OBR segments, can anybody please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by creating  looping for every other segments with NTE segments loop , every segments has the optional NTE segments so iterated with every segment . Now its working fine ...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the message you have *is valid*, but the issue that you may be having is with the formatting of the sample. It looks like a couple of the lines were wrapped. If you properly format them, then the message can be parsed properly.

In HL7 2.x, all new lines must start with a segment identifier (e.g. MSH, PID, OBX, ...). If the line does not start with one of these identifiers, then the parser will not know how to interpret that line or the remainder of the message.

If you are using HAPI and looking to test message, I would recommend using their [HAPI test panel](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/hapi-testpanel/install.html). It is an extremely easy to use tool that can help you verify a message and test message transmission.

Below is a screenshot of what the message looked like in the test panel, once the formatting was cleaned up.

[image: hapi hl7 message]